# tslint doesn't work in my TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, tslint

I tried to add some tslint rules in my ts project, and I found it doesn't work. For example: I added a quotemark single rule but when I tried to use double quotemark it compiled successfully. My tslint is 6.1.3 version, typescript 4.2.3 version. For your information, I paste my package.json, tsconfig.json, tslint.json and webpack.config.js files here.
**package.json:**

```
  "name": "client-side",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "source of ts-learning",
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --mode development --env development --config ./build/webpack.config",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --env production --config ./build/webpack.config",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "typescript",
    "learning_test"
  ],
  "author": "Don",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.0",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.17",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "webpack": "^5.24.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

**tslint.json**

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": [
        "tslint:recommended"
    ],
    "jsRules": {},
    "rules": {
        "quotemark": [
            true,
            "single"
        ]
    },
    "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

**webpack.config.json**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path') 
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: "main.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions:['.ts','.tsx','.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
        ]
    },
    devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        stats: 'errors-only',
        compress: false,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8089
    },
    plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(), 
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/template/index.html'
        })] : [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: './src/template/index.html'
            })
        ]
}
```

Sorry for posted so much code, some of them perhaps useless. But I really hope someone can teach me the solution of this problem. Thank you. Best wishes.

Comment: You should use eslint typescript plugin. tslint is deprecated

Comment: Thank you. So you mean I should use typescript-eslint plugin instead of tslint?